# How can I get node url in rules for facebook auto post

Tags: nodes, rules, social-network

> Event is: After saving new content

[image: node problem]

When I add new blog type content it shows error. I know this error is occurred for

> Set a data value
>   Parameter: Data: [entity-created:field..., Value: [node:url]

```
1. I know the problem is occurred  Value: [node:url]
2. But I need the url of the created node
3. how can I get this url
```

Comment: Anyone here to help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure when you use `[node:url]` in any code, it must be in `""` so for example

```
$path = [node:url];
```

is wrong, it must be

```
$path = "[node:url]";
```

## As another solution

When you *Set a data value* you can use **Value** textarea and `php` codes to generate the node url.

this is an example where I post a trimmed `field_body` and the node url to Facebook. If you need to post the node alias to Facebook, you can use

```
$nid = [node:nid];
$path = drupal_get_path_alias('node/$nid');
```

to get the alias then print it in the `<?php` segment.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Drupalist . The error is encountered in website when I want to add blogs type content there is a title field and it's type is node module element that is not taken more than four words in bangla but english is not problem. I set a value in action element   
Set a data value
Parameter: Data: [entity-created:field-facebook-message, Value: [node:title] how can resolve

Comment: One thing if I disable rule then the field taken bangla words there is no error occurred @Drupalist